# I am going to develop a Job Portal need suggestion

Tags: php

I am planning to develop a job portal in PHP with MySQL problem is we are going to have huge database of CV's about 5 million so need your suggestion how big harddisk should i use to store that much data.

Some suggestion regarding load balancing.

Comment: Your question cannot reliably be answered. How do you know how big CVs will be? What is your DB schema? All this  must be considered.

Comment: I am looking for a rough idea never done big project like this before so... need some ideas from experts.

Comment: put it on the cloud, then it doesnt matter, you just pay more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guesstimate. Your hardware setup should be flexible enough to grow as needed.

If you're going to store CVs as text: one page contains about 3000 characters. Let's say an average resume is 4500 characters, and the data is unstructured - then the required storage is 22.5 GB, well within the ability of a single server.

If you're going to store CVs as PDF/DOC: my resume is ~300K in PDF. If this is representative, you will need about 1.5 TB of storage.

The load balancing question is far too broad to be answered, and does not really relate to the amount of storage you need, rather to the expected load on the service you're building.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not use MySql but a json databse like Mongodb for CV database.

MySQL is a database based on a `relational` model. The problem is that a CV can't be easily standardized to such a model. For example, some people can share they address on their CV, some other people not. With a json format database, every CV can be totaly different. You cannot do that with MySQL (or it will be so hard to maintain)

Second, creating a load balanced database is not easy.
For more information look at the mongodb documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/

(need at least 7 servers).

Hope that help :o

Comment: Can you please tell us WHY not to use MySQL but instead use your recommendations, Without a reason your suggestion makes no sense.

Comment: For plenty of reasons but the most important is that MySQL is a database based on a model. The problem is that a CV can't be perfectly modelised. For example, some people can share they address on their CV, some other people not. With a json format database, every CV can be totaly different. You cannot do that with MySQL (or it will be so hard to maintain)

Comment: "For example, some people can share they address on their CV, some other people not." <--- Perfect case for relation database and database normalization. The only reasons to move from sql db to nosql are speed and clusterization when working with big data.

Answer (score 0):

how about you process each field in the CV and insert it into a separate table. That will help you manage the memory and also save the cost.
Just some efforts to make the segrigating code.

Try making an extraction code in core java

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the cloud solution. I have developed a music site, which may have more than 10 TB data a few years later.

My software stack: Django, Heroku, Postgres, and Amazon S3.

Load balancing? Let the cloud providers worry about that. Furthemore, since I have separated the application server and the static file server, the load is very much balanced.

The only thing to worry is the expense of data storage and network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

If you would like to keep it simple, you can just save the CV somewhere in your filesystem and save the path of the uploaded CV in your database. You can use tags for searching the skills between the users. Get the required CV whenever detailed information is needed.

This way can make your DB with lesser load as the CV data is not on the database and processed whenever required.

But obviously, you need a good amount of storage space. :)